# use a variable in the readmatrix function in matlab

Tags: function, matlab, variables, input, dataset

I have a dataset of train fares across a number of years- my code asks the user to input a year from 2004 and 2022. The code should then display the 3 values of that year from the dataset however it comes up with an error. How can I use the input of the user to determine which sheet data is shown?
The code I've used is shown below:

```
year = input('please select year between 2004 and 2022');
fprintf('you have chosen to see train fares from all sectors in %4.0f',year)
data = readmatrix("train_fares.xlsx",'sheet',year,'range','A1:A3')
```

Ive tried changing the code to show a specific year instead of the variable 'year' and this returns the data just not what is chosen by the user. [This is how my excel spreadsheet is spread out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0q4U.png) The error message I receive says:  Error using readmatrix
The 'XLSX' format is not supported in this context. Set the 'UseExcel' parameter to true on Windows with Excel installed to read and write 'XLSB' or 'ODS' files and
spreadsheets with interactive features, such as formulas and macros.

Error in plot_data (line 4)
data = readmatrix("train_fares.xlsx",'sheet',year,'range','A1:A3')

Comment: The error message is one of the most importatn things to learn about why there is an error.

Comment: Without knowing how your spreadsheet is set up, we won't be able to tell you how to read data from it. However, I would suggest loading all the data in, then selecting based on user choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this

```
year = input('please select year between 2004 and 2022');
```

And per the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) for `input`, it will be evaluated, and therefore something like

```
>> 2022
```

Is interpreted by MATLAB as the **numeric** input `2022`

You need to provide the `'s'` specifier for `input`, which will prevent the evaluation of your input and leave it as a char. Otherwise when you use it in

```
data = readmatrix("train_fares.xlsx",'sheet',year,'range','A1:A3')
```

It's an invalid input, because the `'sheet'` input is expected as a char.

**So your first line should become**

```
year = input('please select year between 2004 and 2022','s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wolfie's answer is correct and I will build upon that in case you need more flexibility (for example, if you want to paramaterize the rows and cols)

cmd = sprintf('data = readmatrix("train_fares.xlsx",''sheet'',''%.0f'',''range'',''A%.0f:A%.0f'')',year,row,col);
eval(cmd)

In this execution, year, row, and column are all integers (doubles) and the sprintf command is forming the command string that can be executed with eval()